# View ignoring its own frame and getting height from subview

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm adding a image to a image view and then adding the image view to a view. The custom view is ignoring its own frame and getting the height from the image view. How can I solve this?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UILabelMe.png"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [imageView setImage:image];

    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    [customView addSubview:imageView];

    return customView;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also implement:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

As [per the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW3), the header view will only work correctly when this is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The above code is working fine. try to add **background color** for **CUSTOM VIEW** and check it.